# List in Recycle view is more then displayed data

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

List all information of both service providers (Babysitter and Kids event planner) from the Account class

```
public class Register_Requests extends Fragment {
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference refAccount,searchdatabase;
FirebaseUser user;
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Adapter adapter;
TextView Fullname_Admin;
Button btnlogOutAdmin,search_bar;
String F_name, L_name;
ArrayList<Account> list = new ArrayList();
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public Register_Requests() { }


public static Register_Requests newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Register_Requests fragment = new Register_Requests();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);}}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register__requests, container, false);
    ImageView imgfake;
    TextView nametext,SPtext,count;
    imgfake=view.findViewById(R.id.imgfake);
    nametext=view.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    SPtext=view.findViewById(R.id.SPtext);
    count= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counttext);
    btnlogOutAdmin = view.findViewById(R.id.signout_admin);
    Fullname_Admin= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_admin);
    recyclerView =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recview_SP);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    refAccount = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Account");
    String Id_admin = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    // Welcome admin
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Admin").child(Id_admin)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           Admin admin_display = snapshot.getValue(Admin.class);
           if(admin_display != null){
               F_name = admin_display.getA_FullName();
               L_name = admin_display.getA_LastName();
               Fullname_Admin.setText("Welcome "+F_name+" "+L_name+" !");}}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something Wrong Happened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}});

    // Logout admin
    btnlogOutAdmin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            perfrences.clearData(getActivity());
            getActivity().finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Login.class));}});

    // List Babysitter and Kids Event Planner from Account
    refAccount.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            list.clear();
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Account a=snapshot1.getValue(Account.class);
                    list.add(a);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                count.setText(adapter.getItemCount()+" Registers"); }
            else
            { nametext.setText("No Available Service Providers");
                nametext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);} }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
    // Adapter for recycle view
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Account> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Account>()
                    .setQuery(refAccount, Account.class)
                    .build();

    adapter = new Adapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
    return view;


}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}}
```

Adapter class where I'll get access from Account class to both service provider

```
public class Adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Account, Adapter.viewHolder>  {
    DatabaseReference Ref,Ref2,check;
    boolean flag =true, flag2=true;
    String userIDs,total_count,IDsitter,IDplanner;

    public Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Account> options) { super(options); }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Account model) {
        Ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Babysitter");
        Ref2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Kids Event Planner");
        userIDs = model.user_id;

        // Print all the Babysitter
        Ref.child(userIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
             if(snapshot.exists()){

                 if(snapshot.hasChild("b_FirstName")){
                 String Fname = snapshot.child("b_FirstName").getValue().toString();
                 String Lname = snapshot.child("b_LastName").getValue().toString();
                 String photo = snapshot.child("b_Photo").getValue().toString();
                 String gender = snapshot.child("b_Gender").getValue().toString();
                 String nationality = snapshot.child("b_Nationality").getValue().toString();
                 String phone = snapshot.child("b_Phone").getValue().toString();
                 String B_date = snapshot.child("b_BirthDate").getValue().toString();
                 int Y_e = parseInt(snapshot.child("years_of_Experience").getValue().toString());
                 String exp= Integer.toString(Y_e);
                 String state= snapshot.child("registration_Status").getValue().toString();
                 String educate= snapshot.child("b_EducationLevel").getValue().toString();


                 holder.nametext.setText(Fname +" "+ Lname );
                 holder.SPtext.setText(model.getAccount_role());
                 Picasso.with(holder.imgfake.getContext()).load(photo).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_name).into(holder.imgfake);

                 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                 AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)view.getContext();
                 activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new eachInfo_SP(model.user_id,Fname,Lname,photo,
                 gender,nationality,phone,B_date,model.getAccount_email(),model.getAccount_role(), exp,state,educate)).addToBackStack(null).commit();}});}
                 else { flag=false;System.out.println("No values");} if (!(model.account_role.equals("Admin"))&& !(model.account_role.equals("Parent")) ){
                     // Log.e(String.valueOf(snapshot.getKey().equals(userIDs)), snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " Registers");
                     total_count = snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " Registers";
                     System.out.println(total_count);
                 }}}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}});

            // Print all the KEP
            Ref2.child(userIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        KidsEventPlanner k= snapshot.getValue(KidsEventPlanner.class);

                    if(snapshot.hasChild("e_FirstName")){
                    String Fname = snapshot.child("e_FirstName").getValue().toString();
                    String Lname = snapshot.child("e_LastName").getValue().toString();
                    String photo = snapshot.child("e_Photo").getValue().toString();
                    String gender = snapshot.child("e_Gender").getValue().toString();
                    String nationality = snapshot.child("e_Nationality").getValue().toString();
                    String phone = snapshot.child("e_Phone").getValue().toString();
                    String B_date = snapshot.child("e_BirthDate").getValue().toString();
                    int Y_e = parseInt(snapshot.child("years_of_experience").getValue().toString());
                    String exp= Integer.toString(Y_e);
                    String state= snapshot.child("registration_status").getValue().toString();
                    String educate= snapshot.child("e_EducationLevel").getValue().toString();


                    holder.nametext.setText(Fname +" "+ Lname );
                    holder.SPtext.setText(model.getAccount_role());
                    Picasso.with(holder.imgfake.getContext()).load(photo).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_name).into(holder.imgfake);

                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)view.getContext();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new eachInfo_SP(model.user_id,Fname,Lname,photo,
                    gender,nationality,phone,B_date,model.getAccount_email(),model.getAccount_role(), exp, state,educate)).addToBackStack(null).commit();}});}
                    else{flag2 = false; System.out.println("False");}} }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}});

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerowdata,parent,false);
        viewHolder viewHolder = new viewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;}

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView imgfake;
        TextView nametext,SPtext,count;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgfake=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgfake);
            nametext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            SPtext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.SPtext);
            count= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counttext);}}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

This is the Account class where I'll save the user's ID. Basically, I have in this class 4 users and just wanted related information of service providers

```
public class Account  {

    String account_email,account_password ,account_role, user_id;

    public Account() {}

    public Account(String account_email, String account_password, String account_role, String user_id) {
        this.account_email = account_email;
        this.account_password = account_password;
        this.account_role = account_role;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getAccount_email() {return account_email;}

    public void setAccount_email(String account_email) {this.account_email = account_email;}

    public String getAccount_password() {return account_password;}

    public void setAccount_password(String account_password) {this.account_password = account_password; }

    public String getAccount_role() {return account_role;}

    public void setAccount_role(String account_role) {this.account_role = account_role; }

    public String getUser_id() { return user_id; }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) { this.user_id = user_id;}
}
```

> As you can see in the account_role these are 3 users and the 4th is the parent
> [image: firebase realtimeData2]

> there are 16 nodes in the Account path
> [image: firebase realtimeData3]

> those are other paths of (Service providers) which is in total 8 nodes
> [image: firebase realtimeData4]

The problem is I just invoked only the service provider's information which should display 8 items in recycle view but here is displaying the rest of the items in the account class which in total 16 items, which means 8 item's data is shown but the rest is empty and I want to display item list as the size of service providers. So How I can prevent this problem?

[image: Run in Emulator]
It's showing empty rows from the Account class.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please include all relevant code into your question here, as text

Comment: There are at least 11 nodes under `Account`, as those are showing in your screenshot. Why do you think the list should only show 8 items?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Because I saved All the 4 users ID in the Account class so, it can be easy to invoke it by its role in the app and ID. But in this case, I only wanted to retrieve information of 2 users only Babysitters and kids Event Planner.

Comment: How is your code filtering the data that it loads to only Babysitters and kids Event Planners? Keep in mind: you shared *a lot* of code, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. You'll need to tell us exactly where in that code the problem occurs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There are no compiler errors that occur while running. Just make it clear for you I've stored All the related data of the account registration for 4 users in one Class "Account " and the rest of the register information through their own classes. In the case above, I only wanted to retrieve information of 2 users which are Babysitter and kids Event Planner (they have 8 nodes in total)from the whole account class. I hope my explanation was clear to you :)

Comment: I am sorry for sharing a lot of codes because I'm new to Stack Overflow and I did not how I can ask.

Comment: To learn how to ask questions in a way that maximizes the chance someone can help you, I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It sounds like you want to [filter the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), but you'll only be able to do that for one value at a time, or for a contiguous range of value, not for a number of distinct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the child nodes from under `/Account` with a specific value for `account_role`, you can use a query to [order and filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Account");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("account_role").equalTo("Babysitter");
query. addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

But you can only do this for a single value (like `Babysitter` above), or for a contiguous range of values (like: from `Admin` to `Babysitter`). There is no way to request (with a single query) a number of distinct values like you want.

Some options:

1. Perform a query (like I showed above) for each value, and then merge the results in your client-side code. The performance of this will be fine, but it will be a bit more code.
2. Give each child node a single property that exactly matches your condition, so for example: `"Babysitter_or_KidsEventPlanner": true`. Then you can filter on that property. This works best if you have a limited number of such combinations.
3. Perform a query on a range of values, for example: `ref.orderByChild("account_role").startAt("Babysitter").endAt("Kids Event Planner")`. Just keep in mind that this returns all nodes where the `account_role` value is between `Babysitter` and `Kids Event Planner`, so it'd also include nodes with `Car mechanic`. Sometimes this is a good option though, especially if you can order/rename the values in a way to allow your query needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your efforts. But I wonder... if I choose to perform the first option how I can combine 2 queries and add them inFirebaseRecyclerOptions to do the rest of the work because I have specific data to retrieve it.

Comment: You won't be able to use an adapter from FirebaseUI in that case, as they can only display results from a single query. But you can add the items to a `List`, and then create an adapter on that. It's not nearly as hard as you may think. For examples, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49599335, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356573 and more from: https://www.google.com/search?q=show+items+from+firebase+in+recycler+view+site:stackoverflow.com